# Flutter WebRTC Playing Audio

Tags: flutter, dart, webrtc, just-audio

I wish to play audio from remote stream of webrtc connection, in Flutter. The examples of flutter webrtc use `RTCVideoRenderer`, but there is no video in my case. The remote stream only consists of audio.

In short:

```
pc.onTrack = (event) {
  // how can I play the Audio stream in event.streams[0] ?
};
```

Code:

```
MediaStream _localStream = await createStream();
RTCPeerConnection pc = await createPeerConnection({});

_localStream.getTracks().forEach((track) async => await pc.addTrack(track, _localStream));  

pc.onTrack = (event) {
  // how can I play the Audio stream in event.streams[0] ?
};
    
Future<MediaStream> createStream() async {
  final Map<String, dynamic> mediaConstraints = {
    'audio': true,
    'video': false
  };

  MediaStream stream = await MediaDevices.getUserMedia(mediaConstraints);
  return stream;
}
```

How can I play the audio from remote stream in flutter?

Comment: I think it need to add to a video renderer.

Comment: Hi. Were you able to play the audio on your part? Please suggest if you found something. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Audio will play automatically in this case, you don't need a renderer if the track is audio only.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).